# python comparing two lists, treating each failure as an independent failure instead of a single failure

Tags: python, list, testing, tdd, unit-testing

in unittest, I am comparing two lists

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.list_to_check_against = ['hu','ge','li','st']

    def test_with_sub_list(self):
        #raise failure for each elenment in sublist not in list_to_check_against
        sublist = ['hu','go','le']
        #???
```

How do I do it? I wan't to be notified of failure for every element in `sublist` that is ont in `list_to_check_against` and suppress output of the lists just the `sublist` elemnts as the list is huge and I cannot see anything in stdout.

Sample output..

```
2 out 3 failures.. 
'go' , 'le' ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_with_sub_list(self):
        sublist = ['hu','go','le']
        missing_elems = set(sublist)-set(self.list_to_check_against)
        assert not missing_elems, 
             "Error: %s not in list_to_check_against"%missing_elems
```

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.list_to_check_against = ['hu','ge','li','st']

    def test_with_sub_list(self):
        #raise failure for each elenment in sublist not in list_to_check_against
        sublist = ['hu','go','le']
        self.assertSequenceEqual(self.list_to_check_against, sublist)
```

If you'd just like to know what missing, you can print the difference

```
print set(list_to_check_against) - set(sublist)
```